# Xamarin Forms WebView won't Refresh/Reload after first load?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am completely new to xamarin.
I am trying to get web view to refresh on IOS after a change.
(following code work on IOS simulator, but not on the real devices, will display a cashed version -- IP address in following code is a local Web server and if i change anything in the website after installing the it wont reflect the change ).

Please Help. What am I doing wrong ?

Cheers

.xaml ->

```
<!--<controls:HybridWebView x:Name="hybridWebView">
        </controls:HybridWebView>-->
<WebView x:Name="webView"
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
Source="http://192.168.1.130" />
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
  BindingContext="{x:Reference webView}">

  <Button Text="&#x21D0;"
  FontSize="Large"
  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
  Clicked="OnGoBackClicked" />

  <Button Text="&#x21D2;"
  FontSize="Large"
  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
  Clicked="OnGoForwardClicked" />
</StackLayout>
```

.xaml.cs ->

```
public WebPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    void OnEntryCompleted(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        //hybridWebView.Source = ((Entry)sender).Text;
    }
    void OnGoBackClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        webView.Source="http://192.168.1.130";
    }
    void OnGoForwardClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        webView.Source = "https://www.google.com";

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Before you set the source you need to find it. Just try this in your button click

```
 var vewbView = this.FindByName<WebView>("yourView");
        vewbView.Source =
            "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38538970/xamarin-forms-webview-wont-refresh-reload-after-first-load#new-answer";
```